# Adding Computer name or User ID to new record in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to setup a simple function to add the computer name of the person who adds a record into an access database. For example if user on computer 12345 creates a new record into table tblTasks then in the field "Owner" it would put that persons computer name.

The way I'm going about this currently (And not sure it's the best way) is, on the form under the field "Owner" I have set the Default value to =owner and I have created the following function:

```
Function Owner()
 Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim wshNet As Object

 Set wshNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
 Set cdb = CurrentDb
 Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTasks", dbOpenDynaset)
 rst.AddNew
 rst!Owner = wshNet.Computername
 rst.Update '<---- Error starts here
 Set wshNet = Nothing
End Function
```

I'm getting the following error when creating a new record:

[image: error message]

I know part of the issue is to do with a validation rule I created not allowing a record to be created without a Task Name but I want to keep that in place.

I'm thinking the issue of the "Owner" field giving an #Error is also to do with the fact that instead of using a button action to create a record I am keeping the ability to just add from the bottom of the record. Which I'd also like to keep in tact.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!
-Deke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on something similar a few days ago and started using the fields like you. I found a solution similar to the macro that you have.

Create a macro event for the form's BeforeInsert property. Use the below code for the macro and update to fit your needs.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Owner As String
Owner = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")

            Me!AddedBy= Owner
End Sub
```

EDIT
Regarding the error that you're receiving, I'm not sure if this will help, but try defining Owner as

```
Dim wshNet As String

 Set wshNet = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")
```

Comment: Sorry a little confused. You say to use the code you have for the On Load event but you have your code setup as using the BeforeUpdate event? Or are you saying to call the BeforeUpdate event from an OnLoad event?

Comment: Sorry about that. For your case, it should be BeforeInsert. I just tested this and it works. You can also delete the IF statement. I'll update the code.

Comment: Got ya! Thanks for the help that cleared it up and I've got it working!